# SPL Token-2022 - How to modify transfer fee configuration for an existing mint?

Tags: web3.js, token-2022

The [documentations](https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-fees) show how to initialize a new mint with a transfer fee, using `createInitializeTransferFeeConfigInstruction()`.

My question is how to modify the transfer fee configuration later? Preferably in JS/TS.

Answer (score 2):

There's a missing instruction creator for the `SetTransferFee` instruction in the JS library, which is an oversight.

It's certainly possible, but only through the CLI currently with `spl-token set-transfer-fee`, e.g.:

```
$ spl-token set-transfer-fee <MINT_ID> <FEE_IN_BASIS_POINTS> <MAX_FEE>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once it is set, there is no way to update the transfer fee for the mint.

Comment: So, once you create a mint with a transfer fee, you can't update the fee later?

Comment: for now you can't.