# How to update Token2022 transfer fee?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, spl-token-program, token-2022

Hello I would like to know if it's possible to update the transfer fee for a Token2022 using @solana/web3 or any other way I've been looking all I i can find is the `createInitializeTransferFeeConfigInstruction` method but I'm unable to find a way to update the fee.

Thanks ahead

Comment: I was told by someone that it is possible it's why I asked since the question was made last year maybe things changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SPL Token-2022 - How to modify transfer fee configuration for an existing mint?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7775/spl-token-2022-how-to-modify-transfer-fee-configuration-for-an-existing-mint)

Comment: Yes thank you @JonC